# Доступ к меткам Яндекс.Карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

У меня есть карта с несколькими метками и есть список, в который должны заноситься отмеченные метками объекты. При клике по элементу списка, соответственно, должен эмулироваться клик по метке. Но я никак не найду их в API.

Как к этим меткам получить доступ?

[Здесь](http://embed.plnkr.co/uuHBqZLiOeKuC81yhMBN/preview) можно посмотреть и поиграться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myPlacemark.balloon.open();
```

Comment: И? Каким образом это может быть связано с внешним скриптом?
____

Сообразил. Спасибо, Друг!